# Issue with jQuery fade in

Tags: jquery, animation, fadein

Am currently trying to create a jQuery fading banner.

However I have noticed an issue with the fadeIn that I haven't experienced before.

When I set the elements to fade in, there is an issue near the end of the fade, that is everything is fine up until around 80% opacity but then instead of continuing to fade smoothly, it just jumps from 80% to 100%

So it makes the animation look choppy towards the end.

You can see it here: https://www.hollatme.com/internship

It happens no matter how long I set the animation to, have also tested in other browsers with the same result.

Thanks!
André

Comment: Smooth here in Opera and Chrome.

Comment: @MetalFrog even right at the end?

Comment: Try it with a different picture.  Perhaps the colors in the image you are testing with give it the appearance of "jumping".

Comment: @Lokase I have tried it with 4 different ones and get the same result

Comment: @AndréFigueira Yeah. I mean, I saw distinct levels of fade, maybe every ten-fifteen percent? But it's flawless now.

Comment: Yup, it was a CSS transition that was mucking with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a css transition set for opacity on all div elements that is interfering with your jQuery animation.

Check line 240 of Main.css

Comment: :D Thanks, that helped a lot! Sometimes just so difficult to spot these little things! Sharp eye!

Comment: That's what stackoverflow is for :). Sometimes it's easy to forget that your CSS might be messing with the jQuery you're using as well. Again, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The fadein is not jumping. Refresh the page with Chrome Inspector open and you can watch the opacity value increment up to 100 without jumping.  I think it has to do with the colors in the image you are using that is giving it the "Jump" effect.

Comment: I have, if you look you can see near the end it alternates between much larger numbers, though it goes very fast.